# Какая допустимая погрешность в исчислении производной по общей формуле и по частной?

Tags: python, функции, математика, анализ

Допустим, у нас есть функция с одной переменной:

```
f(x) = np.log((x + 1)**2 + 1)
```

Нам нужно исчислить ее производную в каждой точке на промежутке от -50 до 50.

Мы можем найти ее производную(частную), ее формула:

```
f'(x) = 2 * (x + 1) / (x**2 +1)
```

Но, в случае, если нам сначала не известна функция или ее производная ищется с трудом, мы используем общую формулу для производной функции:

```
f'(x) = (f(x + e) - f(x))/ e
```

(при е = 0.01, примерно)

Погрешность(разница модулей частной и общей формулы производной, в одинаковых точках) в значении  от краев промежутка( - 50 и 50) к нулю равняется -+ 0.0016( на краях промежутка) и до -1.211 ( в точке 1)

Вопрос:
Допустима ли такая погрешность в исчислении?
Допускается ли такая погрешность ОБЩЕЙ ФОРМУЛЫ ПРОИЗВОДНОЙ, если ее использовать в поиске минимума функции(градиентный спуск)

Comment: Вопрос в том, *для чего*. Зависит от постановки конкретной задачи. Например, точность в метр — это достаточно для расстояния до соседнего магазина, но явно плохо для расчета количества обоев в комнату... И, конечно, считать по такой грубой формуле, как вы привели, не стоит. Даже простенькая `(f(x+e)-f(x-e))/(2e)` уже даст более точный результат. А тут еще и "второй конец палки" — с одной стороны чем меньше `e`, тем точнее математически, но тем менее точно вычислительно...

Comment: @Harry,  я тестил  (f(x - (2 * e)) - (8 * f(x - e)) + (8 * f(x + e)) - f(x + (2 * e))) / (12 * e) , но тут же особой разницы в погрешности не было, возможно в каких то 5 - 7 знаках после нуля. Если использовать такую ОБЩУЮ формулу в исчислении минимума функции(градиентный спуск)

Comment: Если речь о градиентном спуске, то вам же производная нужна только для того, чтобы понять, в каком направлении двигаться при спуске? Для определения направления погрешность не столь важна же.

Comment: С уточнением вопроса — думаю, да, ведь вам надо не столько точное значение производной, сколько направление градиента...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае градиентного спуска лучше использовать частную формулу, так как это быстрее и точнее, тем более если вы это используете в нейросети. Но не надо считать общую формулу ненужной. К примеру для проверки верности алгоритма частной производной функции перед ее использованием, мы можем сравнить ее с общей производной функции. И если они похожи, то алгоритм верен.

Но если вам необходимо использовать общую производную функции или вы не можете использовать частную, то берите "е" поменьше и ждите пока все будет просчитываться (это будет долго), но +- достаточно точно.

Та погрешность которая у вас не самая лучшая, я бы взял "е" меньше.
Если возник еще вопрос задавай.